# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds only at print

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I dont understand why this is happening. without the print statement the code works fine but when i try to print the elements i get ArrayIndexoutOfBounds. For example if i try to feed 3 elements i get exception thrown. can anyone please explain

```
class MyClass
{
    int search(OtherClass obs,target) {
        double a[]=new double[obs.length];
        for(int i=0;i<obs.length;i++)
        {
            a=obs[i].getTarget();
            System.out.println(a[i]);//without this it does not throw
        }
    }
}

class OtherClass
{
    String Target;

    public String getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    public void setTarget(String target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you fix and reformat your code? now it won't compile. Also `a[i]` most probably won't even work as it's not an array.

Comment: ya a is an array. sorry i forgot to declare here

Comment: `class Other class` is not valid - did you mean `class OtherClass`. You are missing lots of `{}`s. The `OtherClass` does not have a length property. All-in-all this won't compile as is.

Comment: and `int search(OtherClass obs,target) {` has two arguments - you've only given a type to one of them.

Comment: `getTarget()` returns a `String` so you cannot assign it to an array

Comment: in your method search, the firs argument is typed ```OtherClass``` (which I suppose is the class named  ```Other``` typo?) now, for some reason you try to access to an array of OtherClasses: ```obs[i]``` where is that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(a)
```

but not

```
System.out.println(a[i])
```

Comment: can u please explain. Why it wont print

Comment: because you take an index of a string that would be like a = "Hello"; System.out.println(a[3]);

Comment: The string is not a list and so can't take an index of it

Comment: does the same apply for int also

Comment: You can't take an index of an int but only of an int array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this, this statement will set value from `obs[i].getTarget()` to `a[i]`

```
a[i]=obs[i].getTarget();
```

**Edited:**

If `getTarget()` method returns an array then you can this way,

```
for(int i=0;i<obs.length;i++)
{
    double a[] =obs[i].getTarget(); // putting the array from getTarget() to a[]
    for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
    System.out.println(a[j]);//printing all the values of a[]
}
```

Comment: does getTerget() method return an array?

Comment: sorry getTarget is not of type string array...but string

Answer (score 0):

In your code `obs` is an array: `obs[i]`; each position of that array is, itself, other array: `obs[i].getTarget() #=> double[]` I guess if, really `obs`has a method named `getTarget()` which returns an array.... probably this?

```
double a[] = new double[obs.length];
double obsArray[] = obs.getTarget();
for(int i=0; i<obs.length; i++){
 a[i] = obs[i];
 System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: `int search(OtherClass obs,target) {` - `obs` is not an array (and also ignoring the fact that the second argument has no type so this won't compile).

Comment: I try to answer it speculating what could anonymous wanted... but when I returned back here, the code has changed. I thought, what if obs is *really* an array (because the final **s**)